# Show MessageBox on others computers

Tags: c#, notifications, intranet

We are developing a program which is used on our intranet. One of the requirement is the program sometimes send corresponding notification on users computer.

Is there anyway for us to run the program on the server (with domain admin account) and sometimes show the notification on users desktop ?

Regards.

Comment: Does it have a database?

Comment: Unless the user don't have the app he can't be notified. You can make a kind of client, without GUI, just running in background and read the notificacions from a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "MSG" shell command.
Type "MSG/?" in command prompt for detail usage.